# PHP Why does strtotime give me the wrong day using YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +15 hours?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, strtotime

When I call `strtotime("2016-05-06 15:00:00 +15.98 hours")` I'd expect `2016-05-07 06:58:48` but instead I get `2016-05-10 02:00:00`.  What gives?

You can test here yourself:

1. Use strtotime: http://php.fnlist.com/date_time/strtotime
2. Convert output int to timestamp: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: It might only accept integers e.g. '16' instead of '15.98'

Comment: It probably interprets +15 as a timezone offset. Don't rely on `strtotime` parsing such complex sentences, it's not magic and it won't get everything correct every time.

Comment: Of note: `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1.5 hours', 0));` results in `1969-12-31 22:00:00` (i.e. +1.5 hours is winding up as -2 hours), so there's definitely some non-intuitive parsing going on here.

Comment: I'd also add that `15.98 hours` is a rather... *uncommon* notation when dealing with times. `15:59` seems much more sensible in this context.

Comment: It is definitely confirmed that it is a problem with the decimal point in the `+15.98`.  For what it's worth, I'm being given the `+15.98` from another system, so while this *is* an odd value to have to parse, I still had to parse it regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
//60 * 60 * 15.98 = 57,528 seconds
$add = round(60 * 60 * 15.98);

$timestamp = strtotime("2016-05-06 15:00:00") + $add;

$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

echo $dt; //2016-05-07 06:58:48
```

This will calculate to 2016-05-07 06:58:48

As for why it incorrectly added the 15.98 hours is more complex. There has been a reported bug for this problem by PHP, though currently **floats aren't supported in date formatting in PHP**. Since you can not directly use floats in date formatting, you must substitute something like "1.5 years" with "18 months", or do arithmetic before and round it like this:

```
//60 * 60 * 15.98 = 57,528 seconds
$timeToAdd = round(60 * 60 * 15.98);
```

And then call strtotime() like in the above example

```
$date = strtotime("2016-05-06 15:00:00") + $timeToAdd;
```

Comment: This is indeed how to work around it, but OP's asking *why* which I think is an interesting question. I didn't downvote, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz I was trying to give a solution, though it is a strange occurrence and is an unexpected output. I don't have too many ideas as to why that resulted. Maybe because it is a float and not an int had to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

**Floats aren't supported in date formatting in PHP**

It seems that you can't do addition in strtotime that way. In addition, a bug for decimal point has been reported [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62353&edit=3)

What you can do is add the time in 2 separate variable just like William's answer

Comment: Was just looking at that same bug and was about to post it; I guess it is now fair to say **floats don't work in date formatting** in PHP.